# What does RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item.HasLanguageVersion() do?

Tags: presentation

I have some logic server side to check if the Item has a language version and based on that the result, the app would choose whether or not to show a particular view. I published the item in `es-PA` language but it is not rendering on the page.

After debugging, I realized that the `RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item.HasLanguageVersion()` check keeps returning false. For a similar item that I published in `es-PA`, the check returns true. Am I missing something?

Comment: Use the desktop page to swap to the web (or prod) database and then navigate to the item.  See if the es-PA is present for that item.  Sometimes it isn't present when the parent item in that language wasn't pushed to that environment

Comment: @BryanEuton it is there in web so I still don't understand why the check is failing